# htaccess url issue

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all pages(domain.com/xxx-xxx-xxx) to new urls domain.com/np/xxx-xxx-xxx and i have tried following rule...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^\-]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+) /np/$1-$2-$3/
```

It works but it is appending too many /np in url, check following for example

I have tried accessing `http://www.domain.com/web-design-services` and it becomes `http://www.domain.com/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/‌​np/web-design-services` can you please explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)/?$ np/$1 [L,R]
```